# Entity Framework Core 5.0 How to convert LINQ for many-to-many join to use Intersection table for ASP.NET Membership

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

**Question:**
How do I convert a LINQ query the performs a LEFT OUTER JOIN on a sub-select that INNER JOINS two tables and has a predicate?

**Context:**
I am upgrading from `Entity Framework 6 (EF6)` to `Entity Framework Core 5 (EFCore)` using the `EFCore Tools` *Reverse Engineering* feature. I have a query that is using LINQ to query a many-to-many relationship on the [`ASP.NET Membership`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membership?view=netframework-4.8) system between the `AspNet_Users` and `AspNet_Roles` tables. The query abstracts away the join through the `AspNet_UsersInRoles` intersection table. As a result, in EF6 I have the following LINQ:

```
(from r in this.DbContext.aspnet_Users
where r.UserId == dpass.UserId
select r.aspnet_Roles.Select(x => x.RoleName)
).FirstOrDefault();
```

That generates the following SQL Query (retrieved using SQL Server Profiler):

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier = '<Runtime_GUID>'

SELECT 
    [Limit1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Join1].[RoleName] AS [RoleName], 
    CASE WHEN ([Join1].[UserId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
FROM (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId]
        FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Users] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0 
        ) AS [Limit1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT [Extent2].[UserId] AS [UserId]
                    , [Extent3].[RoleName] AS [RoleName]
                FROM [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles] AS [Extent2]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[aspnet_Roles] AS [Extent3] 
                    ON [Extent3].[RoleId] = [Extent2].[RoleId] 
                ) AS [Join1] 
    ON [Limit1].[UserId] = [Join1].[UserId]
```

I have converted the LINQ to the following:

```
(from ur in this.DbContext.aspnet_UsersInRoles
 join r in this.DbContext.aspnet_Roles 
    on ur.RoleId equals r.RoleId
  where ur.UserId == dpass.UserId
  join u in this.DbContext.aspnet_Users
    on ur.UserId equals u.UserId
 into UserRolesJoined from UserRoles in UserRolesJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()                              
  select new { ur.UserId, ur.Role.RoleName }
 )
```

That generates the following SQL query (retrieved using EFCore's new `.ToQueryString()` method):

```
DECLARE @__dpass_UserId_1 uniqueIdentifier = '<Runtime_GUID>'
SELECT [a].[UserId], [a2].[RoleName]
FROM [aspnet_UsersInRoles] AS [a]
INNER JOIN [aspnet_Roles] AS [a0] ON [a].[RoleId] = [a0].[RoleId]
LEFT JOIN [aspnet_Users] AS [a1] ON [a].[UserId] = [a1].[UserId]
INNER JOIN [aspnet_Roles] AS [a2] ON [a].[RoleId] = [a2].[RoleId]
WHERE [a].[UserId] = @__dpass_UserId_1
```

The SQL SELECT *statement* from EFCore is different than the SQL SELECT *statement* from EF6; however, the SQL Select *result* is identical. Is this the correct way to re-write the LINQ, or did I get it wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Once I ran the Reverse Engineering tool, the original LINQ command had the following errors:

1. `CS1061` 'aspnet_Users' does not contain a definition for 'aspnet_Roles' and no accessible extension method 'aspnet_Roles' accepting a first argument of type 'aspnet_Users' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

When I add `public IEnumerable<object> aspnet_Roles;` to `aspnet_users`, I then get the following error.

2. `CS1061` 'object' does not contain a definition for 'RoleName' and no accessible extension method 'RoleName' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Below are the tables in question from the ASP.NET Membership system that ***Microsoft*** created. For reference for the full schema, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs

**aspnet_UserInRoles**

```
[Index(nameof(RoleId), Name = "aspnet_UsersInRoles_index")]
public partial class aspnet_UsersInRoles
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(RoleId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(aspnet_Roles.aspnet_UsersInRoles))]
    public virtual aspnet_Roles Role { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(aspnet_Users.aspnet_UsersInRoles))]
    public virtual aspnet_Users User { get; set; }
}
```

**aspnet_Roles**

```
public partial class aspnet_Roles
{
    public aspnet_Roles()
    {
        aspnet_UsersInRoles = new HashSet<aspnet_UsersInRoles>();
    }

    public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string LoweredRoleName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ApplicationId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(aspnet_Applications.aspnet_Roles))]
    public virtual aspnet_Applications Application { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Role")]
    public virtual ICollection<aspnet_UsersInRoles> aspnet_UsersInRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**aspnet_Users**

```
[Index(nameof(ApplicationId), nameof(LastActivityDate), Name = "aspnet_Users_Index2")]
public partial class aspnet_Users
{
    public aspnet_Users()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<Users>();
        aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser = new HashSet<aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser>();
        aspnet_UsersInRoles = new HashSet<aspnet_UsersInRoles>();
    }

    public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string LoweredUserName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(16)]
    public string MobileAlias { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ApplicationId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(aspnet_Applications.aspnet_Users))]
    public virtual aspnet_Applications Application { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual aspnet_Membership aspnet_Membership { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual aspnet_Profile aspnet_Profile { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("aspUser")]
    public virtual ICollection<Users> Users { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser> aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<aspnet_UsersInRoles> aspnet_UsersInRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: First, the two LINQ queries are not equivalent - the original starts from the primary table `aspnet_Users` while the converted starts from the join table `aspnet_UsersInRoles`. Which immediately produces a difference. Second, why rewriting the original query at all? EFC 5 supports many-to-many with implicit join table exactly the same way as EF6, so simply putting the same navigation properties, removing explicit join entity (but configure it since it is using non conventional names) will allow you to just use your existing queries.

Comment: @IvanStoev I have provided an update to my question. I figured if EFCore supported many-to-many relationships then I would not be getting these errors. So, I tried re-writing the LINQ. Do you know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: @IvanStoev: Unless EFC5 added it (I haven't heard about it), EF Core does not support  implicit many-to-many. You need to do it explicitly, i.e. pretend like it's two one-to-many relationships with a cross table you created yourself. [link](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/updating-many-to-many-relationships-in-entity-framework-core/): _"A linking table like this [...] EF6.x created this table for you when you defined a many-to-many relationship, but EF Core, which takes a leaner approach, doesn’t – you need to do it."_

Comment: @Flater It's the top one feature in [What's New in EF Core 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#many-to-many). Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you I wrote this query like this:

```
var result = context.UserRoles
                    .Where(x => x.UserId == ID_TO_SEARCH)
                    .Join(
                        context.Roles,
                        ur => ur.RoleId,
                        r => r.Id,
                        (ur, role) => new
                        {
                            ur,
                            role
                        }
                    )
                    .Select(x => x.role.Name)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This produces query which, as for me, totally fine and more elegant:

```
SELECT TOP(1) [a0].[Name]
FROM [AspNetUserRoles] AS [a]
INNER JOIN [AspNetRoles] AS [a0] ON [a].[RoleId] = [a0].[Id]
WHERE [a].[UserId] = N''
```

**UPDATE:**

If I understand correctly what I've been asked in the comments, then this query will select a role name LIKE LEFT JOIN:

```
var rolesQuery = context.UserRoles
                         .Join(
                            context.Roles,
                            ur => ur.RoleId,
                            r => r.Id,
                            (ur, r) => new
                            {
                                ur,
                                r
                            }
                        );
                    
    var result = context.Users
                        .Where(x => x.Id == "")
                        .Select(u => new
                        {
                           Name = u.UserName,
                           Role = rolesQuery
                               .Where(sub=> sub.ur.UserId == u.Id)
                               .Select(sub=> sub.r.Name)
                               .FirstOrDefault()
                        })
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Which results in this SQL statement:

```
      SELECT TOP(1) [a1].[UserName] AS [Name], (
          SELECT TOP(1) [a0].[Name]
          FROM [AspNetUserRoles] AS [a]
          INNER JOIN [AspNetRoles] AS [a0] ON [a].[RoleId] = [a0].[Id]
          WHERE [a].[UserId] = [a1].[Id]) AS [Role]
      FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a1]
      WHERE [a1].[Id] = N''
```

As you can see there is NO LEFT JOIN, but sub-select will return data in similar way as LEFT JOIN does. Unfortunately, lambda-based queries do not support full LEFT JOIN and the only option to write real LEFT JOIN can be riched with SQL-like `IQueryable`.

I saw a method called `LeftJoin()` inside EF core 5 lib, but it throws `NotImplementedException`. I think it something that will be released later

Comment: @dantety89 Thank you for providing the lambda version of this query. As a learning exercise, how would I add the `UserId` column to the output? As @SvyatoslavDanyliv mentiond, I don't need the `UserId` in the output, but I think it is worthwhile knowing how to add it.

Comment: Replace with .Select(x=> new { x.ur.UserId, x.role.Name } )

Comment: Thanks. But, in the OP, the sub-select with the INNER JOIN joins by RoleId whereas the main select with the LEFT OUTER JOIN joins for UserId. Can you please modify the query to show how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you need just role names for particular user, query should be simplified:

```cs
var query = 
   from r in this.DbContext.aspnet_Users
   where r.UserId == dpass.UserId
   from ro in r.aspnet_Roles
   select ro.RoleName;
```

Comment: I need both the `UserId` and the `RoleName`. But, I am getting the same error that I provided in the update to my question this morning. Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: UserId is known, you do not have to select it. Exception shows that you have problem with navigation property `aspnet_Roles`. It's hard to tell what happened.