# How to return IQueryable LINQ result from two joined tables into a List<string>?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

This is an add-on question to one asked here: [Entity Framework Core 5.0 How to convert LINQ for many-to-many join to use Intersection table for ASP.NET Membership](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66754244/4630376)

How can I return the results of an the following LINQ `IQueryable` result, which is from two join tables, for the `RoleName` column to a `List<string>`?

```
var queryResult = (this.DbContext.aspnet_UsersInRoles
                .Where(x => x.UserId == dpass.UserId)
                .Join(
                    this.DbContext.aspnet_Roles,
                    ur => ur.RoleId,
                    r => r.RoleId,
                    (ur, role) => new
                    {
                        ur,
                        role
                    }
                )
                .Select(x => new { x.ur.UserId, x.role.RoleName })
                );
```

**UPDATE 1**

I need the `List` in the form of an array of values so that I can use the `Contains()` method. I need to search for specific `RoleNames` assigned to a `UserId`. If I use `ToList()` on the `IQueryable`, then the array result is in the form of:

> { RoleName = "admin"}
>
> { Rolename = "user"}

I am unable to use the `.Contains()` method because I get the following error:

> cannot convert from 'string' to `<`anonymous type: string RoleName`>`.

It seems be to expecting a class that the query result can be assigned to. But, one doesn't exist because I am doing this on-the-fly.

**UPDATE 2**

I need the `queryResult` in a List that is in the form of:

> { "admin"}
>
> { "user"}

With this output, I can use the `.Contains()` method to perform multiple checks. This is used for determining `Windows Forms` field properties. So, if the `UserId` belongs to the `admin` role then the form enables certain check boxes and radio buttons whereas if the `UserId` belongs to the `user` role then the form enables different check boxes. This is not an exhaustive list of roles available along with the checks that are performed by the form. But, what is important is that there are multiple checks on the `List` that need to be performed in separate IF statements.

Currently, I am able to use the `queryResult` to do the following:

1. Get a list of the `RoleNames`
2. Perform separate LINQ queries on the `queryResult` by checking for the specific `RoleName`
3. Perform a `.Count() > 0` check to see if the `UserId` is in a specific role.

This seems like an ugly hack because I have the intermediate step of creating `1 + N` variables to retrieve, by LINQ, and store each `RoleName` and then check to see if the `.Count()` is greater than zero. I think that the `List` method would be cleaner and more efficient. If that is possible.

```
var varUser = from d in queryResult
          where d.RoleName == "user"
          select new { d.RoleName };

var varAdmin = from u in queryResult
                where u.RoleName == "admin"
                select new { u.RoleName };

//... more declarations and LINQs ...
```

Comment: I have provided an update to my question providing additional context.

Comment: use GroupBy(x=> x.UserId) after meterialization, then U can search in list of roles

Comment: Use navigation properties, much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**
Select only the RoleName, and use SelectMany instead of Select

**Better answer**

So you have a table of `Roles`, and a table of `Users` (I'm simplifying your long identifiers, not part of the problem and way too much typing).

There seems to be a many to many relation between `Roles` and `Users`: Every `Role` is a role for zero or more `Users`, every `User` has zero or more Roles.

This many-to-many relation is implemented using a standard junction table: `UsersInRoles`. This junction table has two foreign keys: one to the User and one to the Roles.

You have a UserId, and it seems that you want all names of all Roles of the user that has this Id.

How about this:

```
int userId = ...

// Get the names of all Roles of the User with this Id
var namesOfRolesOfThisUser = dbContext.UsersInRoles

    // only the user with this Id:
    .Where(userInRole => userInRole.UserId == userId)

    // get the names of all Roles for this userInRole
    .SelectMany(userInRole => dbContext.Roles.Where(role => role.RoleId == userInRole.RoleId)
                                             .Select(role => role.RoleName));
```

In words: from the table of UsersInRoles, keep only those UsersInRoles that have a value for property UserId that equals userId.

From every one of the remaining UsersInRoles, select all Roles that have a RoleId that equeals the UserInRole.RoleId. From these Roles take the RoleName.

I use `SelectMany` to make sure that I get one sequence of strings, instead of a sequence of sequences of strings.

If you suspect double RoleNames, consider to append `Distinct()` at the end.

### But I want to Join!

Some people really like to do the joins themselves.

```
int userId = ...
var namesOfRolesOfThisUser = dbContext.UsersInRoles
    .Where(userInRole => userInRole.UserId == userId)
    .Join(dbContext.Roles,

    userInRole => userInRole.RoleId,  // from every UserInRole take the foreign key
    role => role.RoleId,              // from every Role take the primary key

    // when they match, take only the name of the Role
    (userInRole, role) => role.RoleName);
```

Comment: Simple, clean, elegant, and efficient. Thank you for the solution and well explained answer - you are a gentleman and a scholar. `Hat tip`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use GroupBy(). Be careful, this method is not supported by direct `IQueryable` to SQL conversion. If you will try to call `GroupBy()` before `.ToList()`, it will throw an error.

In your example you could this: select a list in memory and then work with it:

```
var queryResult = (this.DbContext.aspnet_UsersInRoles
                       .Where(x => x.UserId == dpass.UserId)
                       .Join(this.DbContext.aspnet_Roles,
                                 ur => ur.RoleId,
                                 r => r.RoleId,
                                 (ur, role) => new { ur, role }
                                )
                       .Select(x => new { x.ur.UserId, x.role.RoleName })
                       .ToList()   // MATERIALIZE FIRST
                       .GroupBy(x => x.UserId)  //ADD THIS
                      );
        
queryResult.Contains(roleName=> roleName == "ROLE_TO_SEARCH")
var userId = queryResult.Key;
```

Comment: The Answer isn't quite what I am looking for. I have updated my question.